# PowerShell to select a variable from a Webform

Tags: powershell

Given the code below I am trying to use PowerShell to select "Yes" on the form.

```
<select name="fldQuestion_48159F9B94B2409BAF899C57039D3759_C3E2410FA55F43CA84D9FA6426910A93" id="fldQuestion_48159F9B94B2409BAF899C57039D3759_C3E2410FA55F43CA84D9FA6426910A93" class="fieldvalue formSelect" onchange="this.className='fieldvaluechanged formSelect';">
                        <option value=""></option>
                        
                        
                     <option value="CFFB99C9FB074BC29C1A8ECA6A35203F">Yes</option>
                        
                    </select>
```

I have tried the following:

($ie.document.getElementByID("fldQuestion_438951432F844DA5A8ED19532EBCD50C_19FBC6D011F44E8FA8DF712A1C1F910D") |select -first 1).value = 'CFFB99C9FB074BC29C1A8ECA6A35203F'

and

($ie.document.getElementByID("fldQuestion_438951432F844DA5A8ED19532EBCD50C_19FBC6D011F44E8FA8DF712A1C1F910D") |select -first 1).value = $._CFFB99C9FB074BC29C1A8ECA6A35203F

and

($ie.document.getElementByID("fldQuestion_438951432F844DA5A8ED19532EBCD50C_19FBC6D011F44E8FA8DF712A1C1F910D") |select -first 1).value = 'Yes'

but keep getting errors like this

The property 'value' cannot be found on this object. Verify that the property exists and can be set.
At line:30 char:1

- ($ie.document.getElementByID("fldQuestion_438951432F844DA5A8ED19532EB ...
- ```
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PropertyAssignmentException
  ```

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Sorry, new to the forum and i didnt realize the code wasnt visible.  i have added it above

Answer (score 0):

This is of course basic web scraping using some automation language. Not something that is PowerShell specific.

You have to ensure you are getting the correct form element. Don't guess at it, scrape for it.

***> Point of note:

> Many sites block some if not all automation efforts. Nothing can be done about that.***

Since you are not showing what site you are hitting, here is an example:

```
# Scrape the page for details
$Pwpush = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri 'https://pwpush.com'
$Pwpush.Content
$Pwpush.AllElements
$Pwpush.Forms
$Pwpush.InputFields
$Pwpush.AllElements.FindById('password_payload')
$Pwpush.AllElements.FindByName('commit')


# Full run
$url = 'https://pwpush.com'

($FormElements = Invoke-WebRequest -Uri $url -SessionVariable fe)  

($Form = $FormElements.Forms[0]) | 
Format-List -Force

$Form | Get-Member
$Form.Fields

$password = '1234'
$loginUrl = 'https://pwpush.com'

$ie = New-Object -com internetexplorer.application
$ie.visible = $true
$ie.navigate($loginUrl)

while ($ie.Busy -eq $true) { Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 }

($ie.document.getElementById('password_payload') | 
select -first 1).value = $password
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1 

$ie.Document.getElementsByName('commit').Item().Click();
Start-Sleep -Seconds 1
```